# Stop a Service from activity

Tags: android

I'm using a service in my application but i run it by taking an object from it,as i'm passing activity context to it, so i wanna know how to stop this service from the activity

My Service

```
public class Tracker extends Service implements LocationListener
```

How i start it

```
 T1=new Tracker(MainActivity.this);
```

i tried

```
T1.onDestroy()
```

also in my service defined

```
   public void Close()
{
    this.stopSelf();
}
```

and called it from main

```
T1.Close();
```

but it's still running

Answer (score 0):

To start a service you can do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tracker.class);
startService(intent);
```

To stop it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tracker.class);
stopService(intent);
```

Hope it helps.